# How to receive a file in aspx page from phonegap

Tags: asp.net, cordova, file-upload, file-transfer

wanna help in this
I try to upload file from windows phone 7 using FileTransfer API in cordova and I've followed the steps in the documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)

but i use aspx pages as a service for mobile app I have no idea how can i receive the file in the aspx page
this
encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php") 
I have instead
encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.aspx")

anybody knows?

Comment: Are you trying to download a file from the url http://some.server.com/upload.php which seems to be an page to upload a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Request.Files collection:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["file"];
```